# I am unable to send email in codeigniter using Local Server. Help to resolve this issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, gmail, gmail-api

**Here is my Main function**

The user register successfully but don't receive any email.

```
public function register(){
        $this->load->view("Home/home_header");
        if(isset($_POST["user_register"])){
             $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'First Name', 'alpha|htmlspecialchars|trim|required');
             $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Last Name', 'htmlspecialchars|trim|required');
             $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'valid_email|trim|required');
             $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm-mail', 'Confirm Email', 'valid_email|trim|required|matches[email]');
             $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
             $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm-password', 'Confirm Password', 'required|matches[password]');
             $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address', 'htmlspecialchars|trim|required');
             $this->form_validation->set_rules('country', 'Country', 'required');
             $this->form_validation->set_rules('male-female', 'Gender', 'required');
             if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
                  $status     = 0;
                 $data = array();
                  $data["first-name"] = $_POST["name"];
                  $data["username"] = $_POST["username"];
                  $data["mail"] = $_POST["email"];
                  $data["confirm-mail"] = $_POST["confirm-mail"];
                  $data["password"] = hash('md5',$_POST["password"]);
                  $data["confirm-password"] = hash('md5',$_POST["confirm-password"]);
                  $data["address"] = $_POST["address"];
                  $data["country"] = $_POST["country"];
                  $data["male-female"] = $_POST["male-female"];

                  $data["status"] = $status;

                  $email = $_POST["email"];
                  $saltid = md5($email);


                  if($this->db->insert("register",$data)){
                      if( $this->User_functions->sendmail($email,$saltid)){

                          //echo 'Succesful';
                        redirect(base_url().login);
                        }else{
                            echo "Sorry !";
                        }
                  }
             }
        }
        $this->load->view("Home/user_registration");
        $this->load->view("Home/home_footer");
    }
```

And Here's the mail function. I am getting user email from the input and store the user record to the database. Record stores successfully and page redirects to the login page. But the user don't get email on registration. Help me to resolve this issue.

```
function sendmail($email,$saltid){
    // configure the email setting
        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com'; //smtp host name
        $config['smtp_port'] = '465'; //smtp port number
        $config['smtp_user'] = '*******@gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_pass'] = '***********'; //$from_email password
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        //$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
        //$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
        $config['newline'] = "\r\n"; //use double quotes
        //$this->email->initialize($config);
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $url = base_url()."user/confirmation/".$saltid;
        $this->email->from('gulfpro354@gmail.com', 'GulfPro');
        $this->email->to($email); 
        $this->email->subject('Please Verify Your Email Address');
        $message = "<html><head><head></head><body><p>Hi,</p><p>Thanks for registration with DGaps.</p>
        <p>Please click below link to verify your email.</p>".$url."<br/><p>Sincerely,</p><p>DGaps Team</p></body></html>";
        $this->email->message($message);
        return $this->email->send();
   }
```

If I used any wrong code for this, also highlight that code.

Thanks
Ammar Khaliq

Comment: Have you given permission in gmail for the app to use the service?

Comment: Do not share your passwords to public

Comment: Thanks, Sir. I will be careful next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this method of email.

```
public function sendmail($user_id, $email){
    require("plugins/mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
      'ssl' => array(
      'verify_peer' => false,
      'verify_peer_name' => false,
      'allow_self_signed' => true
     )
    );
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'example@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to
    //Recipients
    $from = "example@gmail.com";
    $from_label = "ABC";
    $subject = "Please verify your email address.";
    $url = base_url()."user/".$user_id."/".md5($user_id);
    $message = "<p>Hi,</p><p>Thanks for registration with Portfolio Times.</p>
        <p>Please click below link to verify your email.</p>".$url."<br/><p>Sincerely,</p><p>DGaps Team</p>";

    $mail->setFrom($from,$from_label);
    $mail->addAddress($email);  
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $message;
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    if( !$mail->send()){
       echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
     } else {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-success pull-right' style='width:400px' align='center'>".'<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>'."Email Sent Successfully...</div>";
       //return true;
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use :

```
echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

after `$this->email->send();` by remove `return`

It will show you the reason why you are not able to send an email

Comment: Then please check where your code is breaking,because $this->email->print_debugger(); always show some output.

Comment: I have got a solution.Thanks

Comment: Good to hear you found a solution, can you please tell me what was the issue?

Comment: There's an issue with default email function of Codeigniter. I used core php mailer function.